# Using enum to set visibility of elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, radio-button

I have a 16 tables that belong in 4 different category's, lets say apples, oranges, strawberries and cherries.

I'm trying to add a filter with radiobuttons that will set visibility to true/false depending on what fruit you chose to filter on (all fruits being visible as default).

So far I have;

My enum:

```
public enum FilterState
    {
        AllFruits,
        Apples,
        Oranges,
        Strawberries,
        Cherries
    }
```

My property

```
public FilterState FilterChoice
    {
        get { return (FilterState)(ViewState["filterChoice"] ?? FilterState.All); }
        set { ViewState["filterChoice"] = value; }
    }
```

The tables (they look the same, apart from the different fruits):

```
 <table FilterState="Apples" runat="server" Visible="false">
      ...
 </table
```

And the beginning of my eventhandler:

```
void filterPolicyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch (FilterChoice)
        {
            case FilterState.AllFruits:

                //How can i set the states to visible?
                Visible = true;
                break;

            case FilterState.Apples:

                break;

            case FilterState.Oranges:

                break;

            case FilterState.Strawberries:

                break;

            case FilterState.Cherries:

                break;
        }
```

I know I can solve this with having 16 different ID's and manually one by one setting their visibility to a radio button. But it seems like excessive work. I also cant change the order of the tabs to use some sort of wrapper since they need to be in a certain order..

And I trying to solve this the right way? If so how can I finish up this :( any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I found out there's no simple way to do this. In the end I had to set ID's to all my tables and then I used the same enum to set visibility in a switch case.

However halfway through I came across enum flags with bitwise operators, and it made the whole thing A LOT simpler. Ill submit my code here for anyone else with the same issue:

```
[Flags]
    public enum FilterState
    {
        Apples = 1,
        Oranges = 1 << 1,
        Strawberries = 1 << 2,
        Cherries = 1 << 3,
        AllFruits = (1 << 4) - 1
    }
```

Beside this I made a help class to shorten the setting of visibility (not needed, but like mentioned shortens the code considerably):

```
public static class TestExtension
{
    public static bool HasFlag(this FruitClass.FilterState e1, FruitClass.FilterState e2)
    {
        return ((e1 & e2) == e2);
    }
}
```

And then "all" that was needed was the events for the sort buttons and the filter function:

```
private void Filter(FilterState filter)
    {
        ApplesA.Visible = ApplesB.Visible = ApplesC.Visible = filter.HasFlag(FilterState.Apples);
        OrangesA.Visible = OrangesB.Visible = OrangesC.Visible = OrangesD.Visible = filter.HasFlag(FilterState.Oranges);
        StrawberriesA.Visible = StrawberriesB.Visible = StrawberriesC.Visible = StrawberriesD.Visible = filter.HasFlag(FilterState.Automation);
        CherriesA.Visible = CherriesB.Visible = CherriesC.Visible = filter.HasFlag(FilterState.Cherries);

    }

    private void filterPolicyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filter = FilterState.All;

        if (ApplesCheck.Checked) filter = FilterState.Apples;
        if (OrangesCheck.Checked) filter =  FilterState.Oranges;
        if (StrawberriesCheck.Checked) filter = FilterState.Automation;
        if (CherriesCheck.Checked) filter = FilterState.Cherries;

        Filter(filter);

    }

    private void ShowAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Filter(FilterState.All);
    }
```

- Cammy out

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing FilterChoice is the variable holding the value.

```
// Replace apples with the appropriate enumeration
Visible = FilterChoice == FilterState.AllFruits || 
          FilterChoice == FilterState.Apples;
```

Comment: That semi-works. I added ID's to all the tables after all and am using enum flags with bitwise chars

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but as I think...

```
public enum FilterState
{
    Apples = 1,
    Oranges,
    Strawberries,
    Cherries,
    Total
}
public void FilterChoice (int value)
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < Total; i++)
        if (value & (counter << i))
            //actions to do if value is set
        else
            //actions if not set...
}
```

I think you looking something like this, I hope it helps.